Understanding the shape of the trajectory in this simplified phase plane control diagram - continuous thrust or impulses?

(image from linked question)
In this answer to Modeling attitude control: ramping/easing between attitude commands? the image above is described as

A phase plane control diagram depicts how the vehicle should respond to errors in the vehicle's attitude and attitude rate. In the simplified diagram depicted above, attitude error is on the horizontal axis and rate error is on the vertical axis.

It looks like there are four limits: $\omega_{RL}$ and $\omega_{DR}$ for rotation rate, $\delta$ and $\phi_{DR}$ for angle error, and the algorithm uses two "gains" $k_p$ and $k_d$ for measured quantities $\phi$ and $\dot{\phi}$ in the equations that determine when the thrusters fire:
$$k_p \phi + k_d \dot{\phi} > \delta \ \ \text{negative fire trigger}$$
$$k_p \phi + k_d \dot{\phi} < -\delta \ \ \text{positive fire trigger}$$
I think I understand most of the trajectory (dotted line) except for the curved section at the beginning, from the "Starting Point" on the left until it levels out to constant positive rotation.
If the thruster is on continuously, there would be a similarly curved line here. If the initial state was negative angle and positive rotation, it would match the shape fairly well. But does the diagram show the thrust slowly tapering off to zero?
I guess I'm trying to understand why this part is a smooth arc, but once we hit the negative firing threshold the trajectory looks like a staircase, suggesting short bursts or impulses from the thruster.

Note very well: Attitude thrusters are never (well, hardly ever) commanded to fire continuously. That apparently is a sign of a bad design.

The "starting point" is in the region where $\dot\phi$ is positive but below the bottom of the upper left drift channel and $\phi$ is negative. The phase plane logic dictates a positive firing in this region. This increases both $\dot\phi$ and $\phi$. The spacecraft later hits the upper left drift channel, at which point engine firing stops. Since $\dot\phi$ is positive, the angle error $\phi$ continues to increase (but $\dot\phi$ remains more or less constant in the drift channel).
The spacecraft will eventually transition from the drift channel to the "attitude hold channel" (which is really just another drift channel). It's only when the spacecraft exits the attitude hold channel that engine firing is once again enabled. At this point, the spacecraft's attitude is very close to the attitude hold boundary. A tiny negative impulse will decrease the rate, but since the impulse is so tiny, it won't immediately impact attitude error. The result is a stair case that eventually brings the spacecraft to an attitude and attitude rate with a small attitude rate error and a tolerable attitude error, both of which ping pong thanks to that attitude hold channel. Note well: These limits are highly spacecraft dependent.
Keep in mind that some spacecraft also have reaction wheels / momentum wheels that provide fine attitude guidance; the engines are only used for desaturation. Some spacecraft have articulating antennae / articulating cameras. Here the engines are used for coarse guidance; the articulation does the rest. Sometimes the thrusters are disabled when fine guidance is needed.

I see, so if the original source and therefore context of the diagram can be found, it would likely indicate that this shows the sue of both a continuous torquer, and an impulsed torquer, and there's some other part of the algorithm decides which to use at any given time?

@uhoh As I noted in a comment to your question, attitude thrusters typically (almost always?) are not used in continuous thrust mode. A long time ago I tried designing an attitude thruster algorithm for use in large commanded attitude changes that did have the thrusters firing continuously. I was told in no uncertain terms not to do that, even if the commanded attitude change was large. 90% on-time per cycle is typically the max.

OK so yes, the curved line shows either that its creator doesn't know that, or that the diagram indicates an additional non-thruster source of torque.

@uhoh The diagram is "simplified". Simplifying things, suppose the phase plane controller runs at the rate implied by the minimum impulse bit. (This means all firings will be at least one minimum impulse bit long.) At the starting point, the relevant thrusters are commanded on because the attitude/attitude rate is in the "positive firing" region. The same will be true at the next cycle, and the next, and so on. The end result is continuous firing until the attitude/attitude rate enters the upper left drift channel, which is when those thrusters are commanded off. (Continued)

There is inevitably a lag between command and response, partly due to electronics, partly due to mechanics (valves don't open and close instantaneously), and partly due to combustion (there's still a bit of propellant left in the thruster, even after the valve becomes completely closed). This lag is why the vehicle continues to accelerate rotationally for a bit after entering the drift channel. This is a good thing as it helps avoid hysteresis. Real rather than simplified controllers oftentimes have extra protection to avoid hysteria such as a Schmitt Trigger built into the phase plane logic.

So now the vehicle drifts for a while in the drift channel. Some vehicles don't have drift channels, but most do. The drift channel accomplishes two goals. One is to keep the vehicle from burning like crazy to make a large turn; King Log vs King Stork. This makes the desired rotation take longer, but at the expense of more time to perform the turn. A lesser goal is to keep the nasty Euler torque, the $(I\vec\omega)\times\vec\omega$ term in Euler's equation, down to a tolerable amount.

Eventually the attitude/attitude rate crosses from the drift channel into the attitude hold channel. Thrusters remain off until attitude/attitude rate exits the attitude hold channel as well -- but just barely. One impulse and it's back in the attitude hold channel. Then it drifts out, back in, back out, back in, back out, ... This stair stepping hysteresis might be undesirable; this is one of the reasons many spacecraft have a Schmitt Trigger built into their phase plane control logc. King Log vs King Stork, once again.

Finally, the attitude/attitude rate ideally settles down to where it wanders in and out of the attitude/attitude rate on opposite sides of the attitude hold channel. I intentionally wrote "ideally". This is a simplified diagram, after all. Reality is a tiny bit more complex.
